# Get an error when giving input to Main (string [] args)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that is going to run through the "Open with ..." menu and give the path file as input to the program. My code is as follows:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (args[0] != null)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1(args[0]));
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1(""));
        }
    }
```

It will run correctly when given to the input program, but when I enter the program without input and normally, I get the following error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: When looking at the answers, be aware that `args` *cannot* be null and nor can any of its elements.

Comment: Here's a good chance for you to get used to debugging your programs. Put a breakpoint on the start of the main function (it will show up on the `{`).  Now step once.  Hover over `args`.  You can see it's an array.  If you click around in the pop up, you can see how many elements it has (likely 0).  Remember that `args[0]` is the first element, so that's where you are getting your error.  By the way, when reporting an error like you did, please include the line where it occurred.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `args` cannot be null, that doesn't mean we cannot check if it is not empty.

Try This:

```
if(args.Length > 0)
{
    Application.Run(new Form1(args[0]));
}
else
{
    Application.Run(new Form1("");
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's proper. `args` will never be null, so there is no reason to check if it's null like all the other answers are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Check `args` to be not empty:

```cs
if(args.Any()) 
{
  // use args[0] here
  ....
}
else
{
  ....
}
```

The error you have means that `args` is empty, so accessing first element(at 0 index) is illegal.

Comment: @Charlieface this was my original code, but  ["The `args` array can't be null. So, it's safe to access the Length property without null checking."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to check whether the first element is `null`, even if your `args` array does not contain any elements. Since your array is empty, you cannot access index 0.